# Validar URL de Verificação de Sites do Google com Regex

Tags: php, cakephp, regex, expressões

Com $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] capturo o seguinte endereço abaixo!

**/google9f7804416f93fdd6b.html**

Preciso efetuar uma validação com ER, a função tem que reconhecer a palavra `Google` os `parâmetros randômicos` **9f7804416f93fdd6b** e a extensão `.html`, para que possamos chamar de forma Manual o controlador `GoogleController`.

Já tentei aqui com alguns exemplos, mas da sempre false.

Comment: Tem como colocar a url completa?

Comment: @rray a url completa seria http://www.site.com.br/google9f7804416f93fdd6b.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boas, penso que esta regex funciona para o que queres:

```
[Gg]oogle[a-z0-9]*.html
```

vai detectar google ou Google, qualquer caracter para os valores random e depois a extensao html. Se quiseres que detecte outras extensões podes fazer:

```
[Gg]oogle[a-z0-9]*.[a-z]
```

Para obteres os valores do que a regex apanhou, basta colocares () à volta do que queres obter. Por exemplo para obteres os valores random fazes:

```
[Gg]oogle([a-z0-9]*).[a-z]
```

Comment: Apenas comentando, @Rui no `[G,g]` a virgula não separa os caracteres, isto não é necessário pode ser posto apenas `[Gg]`, da forma que esta, você esta capturando `G`, `g`, `","`.

Comment: O @GuilhermeLautert tem razão, peço desculpa pelo erro. Já está corrigido

Comment: Sem problemas = D